# Eclipse and curly braces

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a quick way to make Eclipse put curly brace on the next line (by itself) on a block of code?

Comment: This is basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704308/how-to-make-eclipse-automatically-add-braces-to-an-if-statement

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115669/java-eclipse-highlight-missing-brackets

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For pre-written block of code, first do the settings as suggested by Don and then select that piece of code and right click Source Code->Format and the formatting would take place as per the settings done in the preferences.

Comment: You can also use the keyboard shortcut for this, Ctrl+Shift+F, instead of the menus. When there is a selection it only formats the selection - without a selection it will format the whole file.

Comment: and you can add a save action that automatically formats the file on every save.

Comment: @MichaelWiles - Thanks for the suggestion. I had no idea that was an option. Easy to setup too.

Answer (score 58):

Yes, edit your active profile (Java...Code Style...Formatter), and change the brace positions to the next line.  Also, in Java..Editor..Typing, you can have it automatically insert your braces at the correct position.

Comment: I suppose I meant on a highlighted pre-written block of code to having the curly braces on the next line

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, the formatting suggested by the others should do the trick.  I'm a ctrl-shift-f fan myself, but the menus have their place, too.  ;)

Answer (score 30):

Current versions of eclipse have a more convenient way of doing this.

Go to Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter

Click on edit, and on the new opened window, go to the Braces tab.  Here you can choose how different types of blocks of code organize their curly braces.

Hope this helps any who google this, and find this post. (Like myself)

Regards to all!

Answer (score 3):

Coming from C# background I couldn't come to grips with built in Java formatting of Eclipse.

With some effort I managed to get most of what Visual Studio used to offer me. [Here is an XML version of it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpa2yh1bo0yt9u5/C%23%20style%20for%20Java%20and%20Eclipse.xml?dl=1). You can *import* the file..

> Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Import->Apply

Additionally see [arguments on which approach is better](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715) on our sister site..

Comment: Oh GOD, it is nothing but plain xml. May be it complained of not trusting the website, not the content itself!

Comment: Yes, exactly. It complains of the site, not the file itself.

Comment: @andranikAzizbekyan added another link

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and global way:
Go to Window -> Preferences.
Then in search put: "brace".
[image]

Select -> Java -> Code Style-> Formatter
After opening new window go to brace tab and change it as you prefer.

Comment: I couldn't save my brace changes until I changed/made a new Profile than "Eclipse [built-in]. Don't what this is for or if my change will work.

Comment: @AndrewKoper dont create a new profile, instead type in a differnt name and export it!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the methods of changing the settings and ctrl-shift-f to apply, these settings can be done on a per project basis. Simply right-click on your project, choose properties, Java Code Style, and enable the checkbox for "enable project specific settings."

I find this invaluable for use between projects I work on to configure it to match a particular client style, along with other settings to try to match code formatting of existing code. This way, you won't upset other people but can still use your own style on other code bases. :)