# Java eclipse highlight missing brackets

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, compiler-warnings, brackets

I just can't find the option anywhere. Is there some way in eclipse to warn about stuff like this? `if(a==b)continue;` instead of `if(a==b){continue;}`

Or can maybe the format function fix this?

Comment: the checkstyle plug-in may do what you want, not sure though.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704308/how-to-make-eclipse-automatically-add-braces-to-an-if-statement) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is a nice tool which can also be used as a plugin for eclipse.  You can specify different kinds of coding styles you want to enforce on you / your team, by configuring rules in this tool.  [This](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) could help you create your custom check.

Answer (score 7):

`Window-->Preferences--> Java > Editor > Save Actions-->Additional actions-->Configure-->Code Style--> Use blocks in if/while...` here you can configure the style you want.

Comment: Note that this can be configured on a per-project basis, too. Right-click a Project, select Properties, then find Java Code Style > Clean Up in the list.

Comment: @Eric,Agree Eric with your comment.