# A tool/editor to surround single-line (Java/C#/JS) if statement with curly braces preserving it on the same line

Tags: editor, code-editor

Here's what I have:

```
if (something) throw new Exception("whatever");
```

I would like to find a tool which will do a one-time pass over all my code and change statements like the above one to this:

```
if (something) { throw new Exception("whatever"); }
```

**Note that I want everything to stay on the same single line (if it was like this).**

Any tool/editor/plugin/script/anything which can do the job, just once, for all my code - is helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704308/how-to-make-eclipse-automatically-add-braces-to-an-if-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently IntelliJ can do this via a combination of 2 settings:

1. Code Style > Java > If() statement > Force braces > Always
2. Code Style > Java > Keep when reformatting > Simple blocks in one line