# How to change Eclipse settings (for Java) to put brackets on the line after a method/class declaration?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse and curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236531/eclipse-and-curly-braces)

So basically this:

```
public void foo 
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Instead of the default, which is this:

```
public void foo {
    doStuff();
}
```

Just personal preference.

Comment: [Find my xml template here](http://www.filedropper.com/cstyle) to have most of Visual Studio Style formatting

Answer (score 13):

go to windows -> preferences -> java -> code style -> formatter

press edit and go to braces tab

choose braces style that you want for each.

- note that if you don't have any non-built-in active profile you have to make one

hope help

Answer (score 2):

Next time when You forget where it was just type "formatter" in window>preferences.
It will filter it out fast and smooth.

Comment: nice, but it if You pick the wrong option You have to type again ;P